# AWK script to print the number of characters in a line

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to output the number of characters in each line in the txt file after printing the line. The awk script I am using is:

`awk 'length($0)>19 END {print length($0)}' marks.txt`,

but it doesn't print the number of characters in each line.  There is a 0 after printing the file content in the output, but this is not what I need.  Could anyone point out what I did wrong? Thanks!

The content of the marks.txt file is:

```
1) Amit         Physics  80
2) Rahul        Maths    90
3) Shyam        Biology  87
4) Kedar        English  85
5) Hari         History  89
```

The output is

```
1) Amit         Physics  80
2) Rahul        Maths    90
3) Shyam        Biology  87
4) Kedar        English  85
5) Hari         History  89
0
```

Comment: What were you hoping that `length($0)>19` would do?

Comment: I was hoping that length($0)>19 will select the lines that contain more than 19 characters.

Comment: It would but you don't mention anything about needing that in your question so - is there more to what you're trying to do than just printing how many characters are on each line?

Comment: The answer below does the trick.  I have figured out how to get only the lines with >19 characters. I also have found out that the 'END' in the script was causing the problem. The script worked fine after removing "END".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{print $0, length}' input.txt
```

#### output

```
1) Amit         Physics  80 27
2) Rahul        Maths    90 27
3) Shyam        Biology  87 27
4) Kedar        English  85 27
5) Hari         History  89 27
```